# Are these sentences same in meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction

**1. Don't do it until instructed by me.**

**2. Don't do it until you are instructed by me.**

**3. Don't do it until being instructed by me.**

Are the above sentences same in meaning? I think 1. is the shortened form of 2. 'You are' is omitted in 1.

But 3 is something awkward. It seems like incorrect. Does it mean same as the above two?

Comment: They have same meanings in my translator , if English is your second language or you familiar with a second language , you can use translator to examine the difference.So the remainder thing is grammar problem .

Comment: Yes, (3) is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Actually I used 'being instructed' as a noun. So why is (3)  not idiomatic?